# Is std::sort the best choice to do in-place sort for a huge array with limited integer value?

Tags: c++, sorting

I want to sort an array with huge(millions or even billions) elements, while the values are integers within a small range(1 to 100 or 1 to 1000), in such a case, is `std::sort` and the parallelized version `__gnu_parallel::sort` the best choice for me?

actually I want to sort a vecotor of my own class with an integer member representing the processor index.

as there are other member inside the class, so, even if two data have same integer member that is used for comparing, they might not be regarded as same data.

Comment: Can you use [counting sort](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) instead?

Comment: Does your class have any other data members that don't participate in the compator, aside from the integer that does participate?

Comment: yes, as there are other member inside the class, so, even if two data have same integer member that is used for comparing, they might not be regarded as same data.  @SteveJessop

Answer (score 2):

Counting sort would be the right choice if you know that your range is so limited. If the range is `[0,m)` the most efficient way to do so it have a `vector` in which the index represent the element and the value the count. For example:

```
vector<int> to_sort;
vector<int> counts;
for (int i : to_sort) {
  if (counts.size() < i) {
    counts.resize(i+1, 0);
  }
  counts[i]++;
}
```

Note that the count at `i` is lazily initialized but you can resize once if you know `m`.

If you are sorting objects by some field and they are all distinct, you can modify the above as:

```
vector<T> to_sort;
vector<vector<const T*>> count_sorted;
for (const T& t : to_sort) {
  const int i = t.sort_field()
  if (count_sorted.size() < i) {
    count_sorted.resize(i+1, {});
  }
  count_sorted[i].push_back(&t);
}
```

Now the main difference is that your space requirements grow substantially because you need to store the vectors of pointers. The space complexity went from `O(m)` to `O(n)`. Time complexity is the same. Note that the algorithm is stable. The code above assumes that `to_sort` is in scope during the life cycle of `count_sorted`. If your `T`s implement move semantics you can store the object themselves and move them in. If you need `count_sorted` to outlive `to_sort` you will need to do so or make copies.

If you have a range of type `[-l, m)`, the substance does not change much, but your index now represents the value `i + l` and you need to know `l` beforehand.

Finally, it should be trivial to simulate an iteration through the sorted array by iterating through the `counts` array taking into account the value of the count. If you want `stl` like iterators you might need a custom data structure that encapsulates that behavior.

**Note:** in the previous version of this answer I mentioned `multiset` as a way to use a data structure to count sort. This would be efficient in some java implementations (I believe the Guava implementation would be efficient) but not in C++ where the keys in the RB tree are just repeated many times.

Comment: `multiset` would be a very inefficient way to count a few billion integers in the range 1-100. Personally I wouldn't consider it a premature optimization to use a vector or array, since `multiset` will do one memory allocation per element, which is likely to be significant compared with the other operations involved in a counting sort.

Comment: @SteveJessop why would that be inefficient?

Comment: @Hurkyl why not? The end result is the same, plus you get the advantage of dealing with an iterator that returns all your elements if you need them. As I said in my answer, the time complexity is comparable to an array, since `lg(100)=6.34`.

Comment: @Gionvanni: because a billion numbers in a binary search tree will consume much more memory and be much slower to access than a 1000-long vector of counts. (I've removed my previous comment, because Steve has essentially said the same thing)

Comment: @Hurkyl But you are not storing a billion numbers. It's a multiset, it just stores element and count.

Comment: @Giovanni: In full generality, it *can't* just store a count: if I give `multiset` a comparator that says that `x < y` is always `false`, and then store `1`, `2`, and `3`, then when I iterate over it I have to get `1`, `2`, and `3` back (although not necessarily in that order).

Comment: @GiovanniBotta: "it just stores element and count" -- that's not true, test it.

Comment: @Hurkyl I don't get it, it will store each integer once.

Comment: @SteveJessop which implementation are you talking about?

Comment: @Giovanni: In case you haven't realized the ramifications, in the multiset I described, invoking `count(4)` on it will return `3`, because the multiset contains three elements equivalent to `4`.

Comment: @SteveJessop I apologize, you guys were right. I got confused with implementations I've seen in java. Modifying my answer.

Comment: actually, that won't work, I want to sort class by its integer member, while the other member elements are not same.

Comment: You can still adapt that but instead of a vector of integers you need a vector of vectors of your object type or pointer.

Comment: I am not sorting integers, I am sorting my custom class with an integer member, so even if the integer part is same, the two data points can't be regarded as same.

Answer (score 0):

You say "in-place", I therefore assume that you don't want to use O(n) extra memory.

First, count the number of objects with each value (as in Gionvanni's and ronaldo's answers). You still need to get the objects into the right locations in-place. I think the following works, but I haven't implemented or tested it:

Create a cumulative sum from your counts, so that you know what index each object needs to go to. For example, if the counts are `1: 3, 2: 5, 3: 7`, then the cumulative sums are `1: 0, 2: 3, 3: 8, 4: 15`, meaning that the first object with value 1 in the final array will be at index 0, the first object with value 2 will be at index 3, and so on.

The basic idea now is to go through the vector, starting from the beginning. Get the element's processor index, and look up the corresponding cumulative sum. This is where you want it to be. If it's already in that location, move on to the next element of the vector and increment the cumulative sum (so that the next object with that value goes in the next position along). If it's not already in the right location, swap it with the correct location, increment the cumulative sum, and then continue the process for the element you swapped into this position in the vector.

There's a potential problem when you reach the start of a block of elements that have already been moved into place. You can solve that by remembering the original cumulative sums, "noticing" when you reach one, and jump ahead to the current cumulative sum for that value, so that you don't revisit any elements that you've already swapped into place. There might be a cleverer way to deal with this, but I don't know it.

Finally, compare the performance (and correctness!) of your code against `std::sort`. This has better time complexity than `std::sort`, but that doesn't mean it's necessarily faster for your actual data.

Comment: I don't mind wheter extra memory is used, actually, I just want the array itself is sorted instead of creating a new sorted array. and I am not sorting integers, I am sorting my custom class with an integer member, so even if the integer part is same, the two data points can't be regarded as same.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely want to use counting sort. But not the one you're thinking of. Its main selling point is that its time complexity is O(N+X) where X is the maximum value you allow the sorting of.

Regular old counting sort (as seen on some other answers) can only sort integers, or has to be implemented with a multiset or some other data structure (becoming O(Nlog(N))). But a more general version of counting sort can be used to sort (in place) anything that can provide an integer key, which is perfectly suited to your use case.

The algorithm is somewhat different though, and it's also known as American Flag Sort. Just like regular counting sort, it starts off by calculating the counts.

After that, it builds a prefix sums array of the counts. This is so that we can know how many elements should be placed behind a particular item, thus allowing us to index into the right place in constant time.

since we know the correct final position of the items, we can just swap them into place. And doing just that would work if there weren't any repetitions but, since it's almost certain that there will be repetitions, we have to be more careful.

First: when we put something into its place we have to increment the value in the prefix sum so that the next element with same value doesn't remove the previous element from its place.

Second: either

- keep track of how many elements of each value we have already put into place so that we dont keep moving elements of values that have already reached their place, this requires a second copy of the counts array (prior to calculating the prefix sum), as well as a "move count" array.
- keep a copy of the prefix sums shifted over by one so that we stop moving elements once the stored position of the latest element
  reaches the first position of the next value.

Even though the first approach is somewhat more intuitive, I chose the second method (because it's faster and uses less memory).

```
template<class It, class KeyOf>
void countsort (It begin, It end, KeyOf key_of) {
    constexpr int max_value = 1000;

    int final_destination[max_value] = {}; // zero initialized
    int destination[max_value] = {}; // zero initialized

    // Record counts
    for (It it = begin; it != end; ++it)
        final_destination[key_of(*it)]++;

    // Build prefix sum of counts
    for (int i = 1; i < max_value; ++i) {
        final_destination[i] += final_destination[i-1];
        destination[i] = final_destination[i-1];
    }

    for (auto it = begin; it != end; ++it) {
        auto key = key_of(*it);

              // while item is not in the correct position
        while ( std::distance(begin, it) != destination[key] &&
              // and not all items of this value have reached their final position
                  final_destination[key] != destination[key] ) {

            // swap into the right place
            std::iter_swap(it, begin + destination[key]);

            // tidy up for next iteration
            ++destination[key];
            key = key_of(*it);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
vector<Person> records = populateRecords();
countsort(records.begin(), records.end(), [](Person const &){
    return Person.id()-1; // map [1, 1000] -> [0, 1000)
});
```

This can be further generalized to become MSD Radix Sort, 
here's a talk by Malte Skarupke about it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zqs87a_7zxw

Here's a neat visualization of the algorithm: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k1XkZ5ANO64

Answer (score -1):

The answer given by Giovanni Botta is perfect, and Counting Sort is definitely the way to go. However, I personally prefer not to go resizing the vector progressively, but I'd rather do it this way (assuming your range is [0-1000]):

```
vector<int> to_sort;
vector<int> counts(1001);
int maxvalue=0;
for (int i : to_sort) {
  if(i > maxvalue) maxvalue = i;
  counts[i]++;
}
counts.resize(maxvalue+1);
```

It is essentially the same, but no need to be constantly managing the size of the `counts` vector. Depending on your memory constraints, you could use one solution or the other.

Comment: Yeah I mentioned in my answer that you can resize once if `m` is known ahead of time.